# get Object name which is been selected on canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, fabricjs

how to get object name which is been selected or active on canvas , how can i read attributes of object in fabricjs???

```
objcopy = canvas.getActiveObject();
```

i tried ,

```
canvas.getActiveObject().get("src")
```

but it's not working ??

actually i am cloning object and then adding on canvas . but each object has corresponding list field also . so when object is clone simultaneously i want to copy list also , for that i need object name which contains no.

code to clone object ::

```
    var object = fabric.util.object.clone(objcopy);
    canvas.add(object);
    canvas.renderAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to create clone selected active object on canvas fabric following code is worked perfectly for me try this.

```
 <input type="button" id="clone" name="clone" value="Clone"class="Clone">

//*****************Clone selected object***************
document.getElementById('clone').addEventListener('click',
function (e) {
        var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
        if (!obj) return;
        var clone = obj.clone();
        clone.set({
        top: clone.get('top') + 150
        });
        canvas.add(clone);
    });
```